# XML Code appears different on Devices and for Images

Tags: android, xml, layout

This XML Code really confuses me:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:elevation="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/daimajia_slider_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/space3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/space2"
        android:elevation="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Button" />



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/daimajia_slider_image"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/daimajia_slider_image"
        android:elevation="25dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This xml code should Display a picture in "daimajia_slider_image" (it's an image slider from a[github project](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) , but I don't think this has an effect on my problem) and a white frame in "imageView4"

It works very fine in the "Game of thrones" pictures, on all devices, but completely not in that Girls' selfie, on my sony xperia xz and Samsung Galaxy S6.
In the screenshots in which is no white frame visible,the frame is in the exact same scale right behind the image. Have a look at the different images:
[image]

**EDIT**

Here's the java code to that layout:

```
                Glide.with(v).load(getUrl()).into(ImageView4);
                Glide.with(v).load(getUrl()).into(daimajia_slider_image);

//here i do the white framing
                ImageView4.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Its hard to understand your layout. Where come from the white color ? and layout_below="@+id/space2" in Space with -id="@+id/space2" is not possible... I think your problem can come from ImageView scaleType, but with your actual source posted, it's not possible to reproduce your screen display.

Comment: thank you! The white color is made in the java code, after Glide has set the dimensions for the picture, updated code

Comment: I dont understand where you use mScaleType. Can you clean code, naming, format and remove commented lines and not used variables ? It make you question more lisible for people who'd like to help you.

Comment: thanks for trying! I cutted all the unnecessary parts out! Want to have a look?

Comment: I still not really understand how works your layout but here in answer how i'd do that with constrainLayout, hope it'll help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to solve the problem. thanks @smora who brought me on the idea with the multiple Relavivelayouts. like this, 2 problems are solved at once, I could even put on a drop shadow on the RelativeLayouts, which was my problem in another question.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/outerRL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow1"
        android:elevation="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:elevation="10dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerRL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow1"
            android:elevation="15dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/daimajia_slider_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:elevation="15dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_snap"
        android:text="Button"
        android:tint="@android:color/white" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/heart_shadow"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow1"
        android:elevation="29dp">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/outerRL"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/outerRL"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorHeartRed"
        android:elevation="30dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_core_heart"
        android:tint="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its cool that you finally find a solution! your layout seems better like that. Dont hesitate if you continue on android to take a look at ConstraintLayout, its worst it and become as a new standard.

Answer (score 1):

Using ConstrainLayout you can have this layout following this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/daimajia_slider_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/daimajia_slider_image"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/daimajia_slider_image"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Almost! just the imageViews are not accepting the margins, they just fill in the whole screen...?

Comment: Have you test out of your slider, in a simple screen ? it's very strange that margins are not considered in a standard ConstraintLayout..

Comment: I got it! see my answer

Comment: Thanks @smora. I appreciate your effort for helping. If you think my question contributes towards SO, please concider to upvote it!